# Execute a command in the NeoVim terminal emulator on startup

Tags: neovim, terminal

I currently am using a command within a larger bash script to start an instance of NeoVim with some options:

```
nvim -c "terminal"
```

What I would like to do is be able to execute a terminal command from the NeoVim terminal that is opened with this command. In particular, I want to execute a specific version of a Python interpreter.

Something like this:

```
nvim -c "terminal:~/environments/env1/bin/python"
```

Can something like this be achieved with NeoVim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in `:help :terminal`, you can specify a command that will run in the terminal buffer.

```
nvim -c 'terminal ~/environments/env1/bin/python'
```

When `:terminal` isn't given an explicit command to run, it runs the shell.